# I have to filter records by retrieving from SQL table. I want the values in the same field in my table column in sql to not show again

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not able to do so please help. In the code I have written below there are two values in Speciality for program id 1. So is there a way to filter so that value are not shown again in the filtered results i.e. free lunch as specified here. While filtering i am getting checkbox like below, when I am retrieving from database.

a Free meal, Free lunch

b Free lunch

c Free Dinner

I want a to only show Free meal

```
INSERT INTO `programs` (`ProgramID`, `UserID`,`Speciality`) VALUES
(1, 'huy45', 'Free meal, Free lunch'),
(2, 'ga32','Free lunch'),
(3, 'sharvar3','Free Dinner'),
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Xampp Phpmyadmin

Comment: Xampp Phpmyadmin are no DBMS. MySQL is.

Answer (score 0):

There is repeated informations in your table, and you don't want it. [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

I would use another table to store the speciality, such as :

Speciality

```
 id | name
----+-------------
 1  | Free meal
 2  | Free lunch
 3  | Free dinner
```

So you can easilly use a foreign key to store such informations in your table `programs`

Next, you don't want to store serialized informations. This goes against the purpose of using a RDBMS.

I would structure the table `programs` like this :

```
 ProgramID | UserID     | SpecialityID
-----------+------------+--------------
 1         | 'huy45'    | 1
 1         | 'huy45'    | 2
 2         | 'ga32'     | 2
 3         | 'sharvar3' | 3
```

To retrieve the `ProgramID`, `UserID` and `Speciality` for the Speciality name `'Free meal'`, ou can use then this query :

```
SELECT p.`ProgramID`,
       p.`UserID`,
       s.`name` AS "Speciality Name"
FROM `programs` p
INNER JOIN `Speciality` s
ON p.SpecialityID = s.id
WHERE s.`name` = 'Free lunch';
```

---

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Speciality (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(11)
);

INSERT INTO Speciality
  (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
  (1, 'Free meal'),
  (2, 'Free lunch'),
  (3, 'Free dinner');



CREATE TABLE programs (
  `ProgramID` INTEGER,
  `UserID` VARCHAR(10),
  `SpecialityID` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO programs
  (`ProgramID`, `UserID`, `SpecialityID`)
VALUES
  (1, 'huy45', 1),
  (1, 'huy45', 2),
  (2, 'ga32', 2),
  (3, 'sharvar3', 3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT p.`ProgramID`,
       p.`UserID`,
       s.`name` AS "Speciality Name"
FROM `programs` p
INNER JOIN `Speciality` s
ON p.SpecialityID = s.id
WHERE s.`name` = 'Free lunch';

| ProgramID | UserID | Speciality Name |
| --------- | ------ | --------------- |
| 1         | huy45  | Free lunch      |
| 2         | ga32   | Free lunch      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hbjo6a3icrJZGfjm7iHWy9/0)